# Manually insert into Heroku PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, heroku, sequelize.js, sql-insert

I want to add some records in a table on the PostgreSQL db that Heroku offers. I am using Sequelize as ORM.

The query would be this one:

```
INSERT INTO "Categories" (name) VALUES ('Familie'), ('Liefde'), ('Tienertijd'), ('Kindertijd'), ('Hobbies');
```

However, I get this error that says I should also specify two more columns that are automatically created by Sequelize, namely createdAt and updatedAt.

```
ERROR:  null value in column "createdAt" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, Familie, null, null).
```

How can I manually add these records, without going through Sequelize?

EDIT: this is the Sequelize model for Categories:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) =>
  sequelize.define('Category', {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't really need the timestamps, I realized you can specify not to use them as shown in the following snippet:

```
  sequelize.define('Category', {
    name: { type: DataTypes.STRING , unique: true},
  }, {
    timestamps: false
  });
```

This way I don't need to specify the createdAt and updatedAt values when doing an `INSERT`.